# Websphere: web service call on local machine hangs

Tags: sockets, service, web, websphere, freeze

I have two J2EE applications A1 and A2 deployed on the same application server IBM Websphere 7.0. Both applications are deployed on the same profile. Each application has own web GUI and provides several web services, say A1 provides S1 and A2 provides S2.

During normal work process several users are working with GUI, whereas another external systems are calling web services S1 and S2.

Web service S1 in his work also calls web service S2.

Sometimes, about one time per week application server hangs. Users are unable to enter into GUI and another systems are unable to access web services.

Thread dump shows that many threads are waiting during reading from socket. All these threads are local web service calls. At the same time there are about 5 free threads in web container pool. Total CPU load is less than 10%. Memory usage is also OK. Garbage collector is not running, when GC is running it takes about 200 ms, so GC is not a reason for hang.

So my questions are:

1. Why local web service call hang?
2. Why users are unable to access web GUI when there are a few free threads in web container pool?

=====

Web container threads:

```
WebContainer : 0    Runnable    3836    java/net/SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)   68
WebContainer : 1    Runnable    3840    java/net/SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)   68
WebContainer : 10   Runnable    1352    java/net/SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)   68
WebContainer : 11   Waiting on condition    1736    java/lang/StackTraceElement.appendTo(StackTraceElement.java:180(Compiled Code)) 74
WebContainer : 12   Waiting on condition    3444    java/net/SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)   68
WebContainer : 13   Runnable    3056    java/net/SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)   68
WebContainer : 14   Runnable    3508    java/net/SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)   68
WebContainer : 15   Runnable    3344    java/net/SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)   68
WebContainer : 16   Runnable    1592    java/net/SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)   68
WebContainer : 17   Waiting on condition    1744    java/net/SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)   68
WebContainer : 18   Waiting on condition    2108    java/net/SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)   68
WebContainer : 19   Runnable    684 java/net/SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)   68
WebContainer : 2    Runnable    1552    java/net/SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)   68
WebContainer : 20   Runnable    4824    java/net/SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)   68
WebContainer : 21   Runnable    4132    java/net/SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)   68
WebContainer : 22   Runnable    4116    java/net/SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)   68
WebContainer : 23   Runnable    4164    java/net/SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)   68
WebContainer : 24   Runnable    2668    java/net/SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)   68
WebContainer : 25   Runnable    4212    java/net/SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)   68
WebContainer : 26   Runnable    4020    java/net/SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)   68
WebContainer : 27   Runnable    496 java/net/SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)   68
WebContainer : 28   Runnable    2448    java/net/SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)   68
WebContainer : 29   Runnable    3428    java/net/SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)   68
WebContainer : 3    Runnable    3908    java/net/SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)   68
WebContainer : 30   Runnable    4168    java/net/SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)   68
WebContainer : 31   Runnable    4160    java/net/SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)   68
WebContainer : 32   Runnable    3328    java/net/SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)   68
WebContainer : 33   Runnable    3348    java/net/SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)   69
WebContainer : 34   Runnable    3324    java/net/SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)   68
WebContainer : 35   Runnable    4308    java/net/SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)   68
WebContainer : 36   Blocked 3164    java/lang/Object.wait(Native Method)    6
WebContainer : 37   Blocked 852 java/lang/Object.wait(Native Method)    6
WebContainer : 38   Waiting on condition    4288    java/lang/Object.wait(Native Method)    6
WebContainer : 39   Blocked 5056    java/lang/Object.wait(Native Method)    6
WebContainer : 4    Runnable    2400    java/net/SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)   68
WebContainer : 5    Runnable    4092    java/net/SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)   68
WebContainer : 6    Runnable    3968    java/net/SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)   68
WebContainer : 7    Runnable    1832    java/net/SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)   68
WebContainer : 8    Waiting on condition    3356    java/net/SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)   68
WebContainer : 9    Runnable    2236    java/net/SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)   68
```

=====

Threads 36-39 are free:

```
at java/lang/Object.wait(Native Method) 
at java/lang/Object.wait(Object.java:196(Compiled Code)) 
at com/ibm/ws/util/BoundedBuffer.waitGet_(BoundedBuffer.java:187(Compiled Code)) 
at com/ibm/ws/util/BoundedBuffer.take(BoundedBuffer.java:549(Compiled Code)) 
at com/ibm/ws/util/ThreadPool.getTask(ThreadPool.java:899(Compiled Code)) 
at com/ibm/ws/util/ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1653(Compiled Code))
```

=====

Almost all rest threads have the same stack trace:

```
at java/net/SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method) 
at java/net/SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:140(Compiled Code)) 
at java/io/BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:229(Compiled Code)) 
at java/io/BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:248(Compiled Code)) 
at org/apache/axis/transport/http/HTTPSender.readHeadersFromSocket(HTTPSender.java:583(Compiled Code)) 
at org/apache/axis/transport/http/HTTPSender.invoke(HTTPSender.java:143(Compiled Code)) 
at org/apache/axis/strategies/InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32(Compiled Code)) 
at org/apache/axis/SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118(Compiled Code)) 
at org/apache/axis/SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83(Compiled Code)) 
at org/apache/axis/client/AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:165(Compiled Code)) 
at org/apache/axis/client/Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784(Compiled Code)) 
at org/apache/axis/client/Call.invoke(Call.java:2767(Compiled Code)) 
at org/apache/axis/client/Call.invoke(Call.java:2443(Compiled Code)) 
at org/apache/axis/client/Call.invoke(Call.java:2366(Compiled Code)) 
at org/apache/axis/client/Call.invoke(Call.java:1812(Compiled Code)) 

call web service S2 on the same host here
...
My web service code here.
...
at sun/reflect/GeneratedMethodAccessor366.invoke(Bytecode PC:124(Compiled Code)) 
at sun/reflect/DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37(Compiled Code)) 
at java/lang/reflect/Method.invoke(Method.java:611(Compiled Code)) 
at org/apache/axis/providers/java/RPCProvider.invokeMethod(RPCProvider.java:397(Compiled Code)) 
at org/apache/axis/providers/java/EJBProvider.invokeMethod(EJBProvider.java:459(Compiled Code)) 
at org/apache/axis/providers/java/RPCProvider.processMessage(RPCProvider.java:186(Compiled Code)) 
at org/apache/axis/providers/java/JavaProvider.invoke(JavaProvider.java:323(Compiled Code)) 
at org/apache/axis/strategies/InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32(Compiled Code)) 
at org/apache/axis/SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118(Compiled Code)) 
at org/apache/axis/SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83(Compiled Code)) 
at org/apache/axis/handlers/soap/SOAPService.invoke(SOAPService.java:454(Compiled Code)) 
at org/apache/axis/server/AxisServer.invoke(AxisServer.java:281(Compiled Code)) 
at org/apache/axis/transport/http/AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:699(Compiled Code)) 
at javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:738(Compiled Code)) 
at org/apache/axis/transport/http/AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327(Compiled Code)) 
at javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831(Compiled Code)) 
at com/ibm/ws/webcontainer/servlet/ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1657(Compiled Code)) 
at com/ibm/ws/webcontainer/servlet/ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1597(Compiled Code)) 
at com/ibm/ws/webcontainer/filter/WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:131(Compiled Code)) 

at com/ibm/ws/webcontainer/filter/FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188(Compiled Code)) 
at com/ibm/ws/webcontainer/filter/WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116(Compiled Code)) 
at com/ibm/ws/webcontainer/filter/WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:77(Compiled Code)) 
at com/ibm/ws/webcontainer/filter/WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:908(Compiled Code)) 
at com/ibm/ws/webcontainer/servlet/ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:934(Compiled Code)) 
at com/ibm/ws/webcontainer/servlet/ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:502(Compiled Code)) 
at com/ibm/ws/webcontainer/servlet/ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:181(Compiled Code)) 
at com/ibm/ws/webcontainer/servlet/CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:91(Compiled Code)) 
at com/ibm/ws/webcontainer/WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:864(Compiled Code)) 
at com/ibm/ws/webcontainer/WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1592(Compiled Code)) 
at com/ibm/ws/webcontainer/channel/WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:186(Compiled Code)) 
at com/ibm/ws/http/channel/inbound/impl/HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:452(Compiled Code)) 
at com/ibm/ws/http/channel/inbound/impl/HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:511(Compiled Code)) 
at com/ibm/ws/http/channel/inbound/impl/HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:305(Compiled Code)) 
at com/ibm/ws/http/channel/inbound/impl/HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:276(Compiled Code)) 
at com/ibm/ws/tcp/channel/impl/NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214(Compiled Code)) 
at com/ibm/ws/tcp/channel/impl/NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113(Compiled Code)) 
at com/ibm/ws/tcp/channel/impl/AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165(Compiled Code)) 
at com/ibm/io/async/AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217(Compiled Code)) 
at com/ibm/io/async/AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161(Compiled Code)) 
at com/ibm/io/async/AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138(Compiled Code)) 
at com/ibm/io/async/ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204(Compiled Code)) 
at com/ibm/io/async/ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775(Compiled Code)) 
at com/ibm/io/async/ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905(Compiled Code)) 
at com/ibm/ws/util/ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1646(Compiled Code))
```

Thanks.

Stan

Comment: Not that I'll have any answers for you, but to clarify for someone who might... is this using WebSphere JAX-WS (based on Axis), or are you using Axis manually? I certainly can't explain why it would hang if you really do have WebContainer threads free. Have you looked at the PMI data?

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
We are using SoapBindingStub generated by wsdl2java. Nothing critical in PMI data.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that all threads are locked to wait something. Usually in this situation a timeout should break the lock; if it does not happen:

- Somewhere in configuration timeout are set to 0 (infinite)
- The application logic generate a sort of multiplier effect. Example: a query takes a long time, the user submit again the query that takes more and lock an other web thread, the exception trigger a web service call, and so on.

On DB side, are there any dead locks?